# How can I make Unity maximize windows like Gnome 2, KDE, Xfce et al?

Tags: unity, 12.10, window-decoration

Unity, of course, puts the window buttons and menus at the top left for maximized windows and removes the titlebar. I hate this. Is there a way to make it stop and just make the windows as big as the screen? I'm in 12.10, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is **making the windows as big as the screen**, then it is as simple as setting the Launcher behavior.

[image: Set the Launcher behavior.]

1. Open **Appearance** from the Dash or **Device Menu** > **System Settings...** > **Appearance**
2. Select **Behavior** tab
3. Set **Auto-hide the Launcher** to **ON**

The result will be like this:

[image: The entire screen is used now.]

Comment: No, what we really want is for the titlebar to behave normally instead of hiding buttons and text depending on where your mouse is.